# Android designer complains when I tryo to use design support library components

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying to implement a `TabLayout` for my application, so I add the support libraries, head into the XML editor of Android Studio, and begin typing `<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>`. I get the usual issues of having to set a height and width, but I also seem a NOTE below stating:

```
Failed to find '?attr/colorPrimaryDark' in current theme. 
(3 similar errors not shown)
```

Ok, I have and `android:colorPrimaryDark` set in my `styles.xml`. I have no idea what this `?attr/colorPrimaryDark` is so I attempt to add it to my styles (which inherit from `Theme.Material.Light`) like:

```
<item name="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">#abcdef</item>
```

This does not fix the issue. Why am I getting this message? How do I fix the issue with this support library?

Comment: Can you include your style code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the color palette in your style once your theme inherits the material theme.

Here is the code suggested on the google documentation.

```
    <resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

In this code, they are referencing to their colors.xml resource file, but you can hard code colors straight into the style file.

One this is done, make sure that you don't have conflicting styles in different values folders in your resources.

Comment: I did all of this, yet it still complains.

Comment: You don't have another style.xml file in another values folder that would be conflicting? Another trivial thing is to make sure that you use the latest versions of the support libraries in the Gradle file. Double check with the SDK manager.

Comment: Could styles (v21) conflict?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am saying. Decide whether or not you need this file since you are using the support library anyway.